# GNU-make 4. Running an example for "Loading Dynamic Objects"

Tags: c, linux, makefile

> The latest version of GNU-Make http://www.gnu.org/software/make/
>   provides many advanced capabilities, including many useful functions.
>   (...) On systems which support dynamically loadable objects, you can
>   write your own extension in any language (which can be compiled into
>   such an object) and load it to provide extended capabilities... http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Loading-Objects

I tried to run the simple example below (a $(hello string) function). It works if I first compile the hello.so. But it doesn't work if I run it as the example provided here (with a `load` directive) http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Loading-Objects  . Make4 is installed in the current directory.

./Makefile:

```
all:
    echo $(hello world)

load hello.so

hello.so: hello.c
    $(CC) -shared -I./include -fPIC -o $@ $<
```

./hello.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <gnumake.h>

int plugin_is_GPL_compatible;

char * hello(const char *nm, unsigned int argc, char **argv)
    {
    int len = strlen (argv[0]) + 7;
    char *buf = gmk_alloc (len);
    sprintf(buf,"Hello %s",argv[0]);
    return buf;
    }

int hello_gmk_setup ()
    {
    gmk_add_function("hello", hello, 1, 1, 1);
    return 1;
    }
```

running the example:

```
 ./bin/make -v
GNU Make 4.0
Built for i686-pc-linux-gnu

$ ./bin/make 
Makefile:4: hello.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makefile:4: *** hello.so: failed to load.  Stop.
```

How can I run this example with the 'load' directive ?

Comment: FYI: I've just posted my question to the make-help mailing list.

Comment: shouldn't `all` simply depend on `hello.so`?

Comment: Try `load ./hello.so` ; because `dlopen` handles specially paths without `/`; also `all` should depend upon `hello.so`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch nice suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: BTW, you need `hello.so` to exist before `load`-ing it. Perhaps use `-load` instead of `load`

Comment: @user538603 no,( I tried but it didn't work). See the example in the manual http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Loaded-Object-Example

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch cool it worked ! Please move your comment to an answer so I can validate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest in a comment to use

```
-load hello.so
```

instead of just `load hello.so`; this is analog to using `-include` in a `Makefile`.

The logic is that `make` plugins are generally expected to exit before you run some `make` using them (often, you would use a recursive make, e.g. run `$(MAKE) -C subdir` in a toplevel `Makefile` and ensure that the plugin does exist when your run `$(MAKE) -C subdir`)

If `hello.so` does not exist when `-load hello.so` is parsed, the GNU `make` would ignore that directive. (I am not sure you want that for a real plugin).

I still think that `make` plugins should generally not be built by the `Makefile` which is `load`-ing them.

I also believe that using *Guile* extensions in `make` is wiser than using plugins.